# Sharing images from drawable by saving in internal storage

Tags: android, external, sharing, internal, saving-data

I have about 10 images in my app and they are in drawable resorses, not downloading from server.

I need to share this images.

I've got solution like this: convert drawable to file, save it and share file from folder.

Everething is ok with External Storage, when I got a sd-card. But when I am using Nexus 5, for example(Internal Storage) it save some file, but doesn't share it, because of unnormal format.

Please, help me with internal storage or with sharing from drawable.

```
private void shareit()
    {

        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.son); 

        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/jpeg");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

        File f;             

        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            // We can read and write the media
            f=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "son.jpg");
        }
        else{
            f = new File(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), "son.jpg");
            if(f.exists()){
                Log.i("imageExistsInternal", "file is complete");
            }
        }
        if(!f.exists())
            f.mkdir();
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
    }
```

Comment: multiple problems in sharing images. all fixed here. read question, answer and the conversation.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101881/how-to-always-save-image-with-new-name-and-delete-previouse-one-android

Comment: tried to use, but it works only with external storage

Answer (score 0):

In your code above, you didn't write your image to the file. If the image doesn't exist, a directory will be created, so the format is wrong.

```
  if(!f.exists())
      f.mkdir();
```

You need to change like this

```
if (!f.exists()) {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
            outputStream.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: unforunatuly, it doesnt help me. Maybe another ideas?